# updating yii form record with uploaded file it throw an error if i don't attach the file again

Tags: yii

when i create a new record in my yii form with uploaded file, it's working fine, but when i update ihave to attach the file again or else it will give error
here is my controller file, please tell me what is my mistake
my uploaded file is an image, what i want is to change one field let's say the date and keep the rest as is including the uploaded file, but if don't attach the file again it will give an error

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement;
use app\models\JetskiDamageSettlementAgreementSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * JetskiDamageSettlementAgreementController implements the CRUD actions for JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement model.
 */
class JetskiDamageSettlementAgreementController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new JetskiDamageSettlementAgreementSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            // get the instance of the uploaded file
            $model->damage_image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'damage_image');
            $image_name = $model->customer_name.'.'.$model->damage_image->extension;
            $image_path = 'attachments/' .$image_name;
            $model->damage_image->saveAs($image_path);
            $model->damage_image = $image_path;

            $model->agreement_date = date ('y-m-d h:m:s');
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->agreement_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $model->damage_image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'damage_image');
            $image_name = $model->customer_name.'.'.$model->damage_image->extension;
            $image_path = 'attachments/' .$image_name;
            $model->damage_image->saveAs($image_path);
            $model->damage_image = $image_path;

            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->agreement_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = JetskiDamageSettlementAgreement::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are getting the error because of your rules set to that model. In your model rules, this field for the file is set to be **required** for all scenarios.

One possible solution is to set the field to be required only on **insert** scenario and leave **update** scenario to be not required for the field. But this really depends on business logic that you need to satisfy.

Comment: Thanks Zmilan, sounds a reasonable solution, but actually i prefer if possible to set it as "not required" but to keep having the existing file

Comment: and where is that rule, when i can modify?

Comment: Rules are set inside your Model. You can tweak your rules to match the exact need for your business logic. If you use Gii to generate your models from the database table then Gii applies rules based on your database table rules. I suppose that the file field in the database is required and that is why rules ended up like required. But you can adjust that further. So you can make it required for new records and not required for existing records (because they will have it already because it is required for new records), or even create your own validator that would do some more detail inspection

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation, i got exactly your points

Comment: @Rashwan you are welcome. I'm glad that I could help :)